# Non-linear Lie algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

Several versions of non-linear Lie algebras exist - at least in the physics literature. One version is just an ordinary Lie algebra but where the underlying vector space is a polynomial algebra.
Another is a `field dependent' version of a Lie algebra.
The quadratic case at least is physically relevant. Any really mathematical references available?

Comment: Can you give some physics references?

Comment: Can you also elaborate a bit on what you mean by "non linear"? (Maybe by fleshing out the examples you hinted at)

Comment: To elaborate on @Qfwfq's question:  by "non-linear" do you mean "not the Lie algebra of a finite-dimensional linear Lie group"?

Comment: Thanks for pushing me: Ikeda Two-dimensional gravity and nonlinear gauge theory with references to special cases - e.g W-algebras.  One version is just a strict Lie algebra with underly8ng vector space a free polynomial algebra. Others seem to be field dependent.

Comment: You've referred twice to field dependence, but it's still not clear what that means.  What is an example of a field-dependent Lie algebra, or version of a Lie algebra?  What condition on them makes you call them 'non-linear'?

Comment: see my paper with Fulp and LadaSH-LIE ALGEBRAS INDUCED BY GAUGE TRANSFORMATionsThe physics of \particles of spin  2" leads to representations of a
Lie algebra  of gauge parameters on a vector space  of elds. A
signicant generalization occurs when the gauge parameters act in a
eld dependent way. By a eld dependent action of  on ; Berends,
Burgers and van Dam [Bur85, BBvD86, BBvD85] mean a polynomial
(or power series) map ()() = i0Ti(; ) where Ti is linear in  and
polynomial of homogeneous degree i in :

Answer (score 1):

The main reference I can find is de Sole and Kac's papers https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0312042 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0511055.

**Definition:** [p2 of first paper] A *nonlinear Lie algebra* is a $\mathbf{Z}_{\ge 0}$-graded  vector space $L$ along with a map to the tensor algebra
$$L\wedge L\ \to\ T(L)$$
respecting the grading $|[\alpha,\beta]|\le |\alpha|+|\beta|$ (having extended the grading to $T(L)$ in the obvious way) and such that
$$ (\text{Jacobi identity for }\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$
is a sum of elements of the form $a\otimes (b\otimes c-c\otimes b-[b,c])\otimes d$  with total degree $<|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|$.

You can then define $U(L)$ as the quotient of $T(L)$ by the ideal generated by elements of this form (with any degree).

---

About "field dependence": there are in fact four different notions:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\text{Lie algebra} @. \text{non-linear Lie algebra} \\
@. @. \\
\text{Lie conformal algebra} @. \text{non-linear Lie conformal algebra}
\end{CD}$$
and the bottom row are "vertex algebra" sort of objects, i.e. depend on a parameter $z\in \mathbf{A}^1$.

Comment: It's terrible to make a definition of "non-P" which is something else than the negation of some given Property P. I hope subsequent papers will opt for a more reasonable terminology.

Comment: Reminds me of the definition of noncommutative spaces (which *includes* commutative spaces).